# Emacs regex matching end of line followed by new line

Tags: regex, emacs

The match for the empty line followed by the new line fails for the regex `^$^J` but succeeds for the regex `^^J`. What is wrong with the former regex?

Answer (score 5):

`$` in a regexp usually matches the empty string at an end of line, but in reality this is only true if the `$` appears at specific places in the regexp (e.g. at the end of the regexp, or at the end of a sub-group, IIRC).  If the `$` appears "in the middle" it just matches the `$` character.  Same applies to `^`.  E.g. `(string-match "a^b$c" "1a^b$c2")` returns 1.

<kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(emacs) Regexps` documents this behaviour:

```
‘^’
     is a special character that matches the empty string, but only at
     the beginning of a line in the text being matched.  Otherwise it
     fails to match anything.  Thus, ‘^foo’ matches a ‘foo’ that occurs
     at the beginning of a line.

     For historical compatibility reasons, ‘^’ can be used with this
     meaning only at the beginning of the regular expression, or after
     ‘\(’ or ‘\|’.

‘$’
     is similar to ‘^’ but matches only at the end of a line.  Thus,
     ‘x+$’ matches a string of one ‘x’ or more at the end of a line.

     For historical compatibility reasons, ‘$’ can be used with this
     meaning only at the end of the regular expression, or before ‘\)’
     or ‘\|’.
```